# How to add Facebook Login script to React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, material-ui

[image]

How to add Facebook Login script not get syntacs error to React?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login take a look at that package...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because ,  tags are not directly added to ReactJS Code. If you want to add some code snippet in  tags, add it to **index.html** in **public/** folder and it will work with all the html of the components, that you will right inside reactJs files(handle any other adjustments necessary like: giving specific id or classname on div for your script to work) since, at the end of it when you run node server, all the js will be rendered inside the index.html in **"root"** div.